# RavenDB on a port other than 8080

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

We are trying to install NServiceBus 4.2.0.0 with RavenDB via the following command:-

```
    nserviceBus.host.exe -install serviceName="xxxx.Server" -displayname="xxxx.Server" -username="domainName\serviceAccountName" -password="serviceAccountPassword"
```

NServiceBus seems to install however the RavenDB install fails - note we are trying to install under a port other than 8080 - as a result we have placed the line:-

```
    <add name="NServiceBus/Persistence" connectionString="Url = http://localhost:9090" />
```

...in our config

The error message we receive is:-

```
    [1] WARN  NServiceBus.ConfigureRavenPersistence [(null)] <(null)> - Raven could not be contacted. We tried to access Raven using the following url: http://localhost:9090.
```

If I leave at the default port (8080), everything installs correctly, however I need to change the port because 8080 is already in use

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

RavenDB installation is separate from NServiceBus host installation.

To install RavenDB either follow the instructions on RavenDB website or you can install Raven server by using the NServiceBus Powershell cmdlets, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/managing-nservicebus-using-powershell for instructions on how to load the cmdlets.
If you choose to use the cmdlets, you need to execute `Install-NServiceBusRavenDB -Port 9090`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the RavenDB port, you can do the following:

Note: The paths defined here are from the NServiceBus 4.3.2 installer with default paths 

To download the installer, you can visit here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/releases/download/4.3.2/Particular.NServiceBus-4.3.2.exe

> 1. Launch the services management window (i.e. Run services.msc)
> 2. Stop service RavenDB
> 3. Navigate to the following path: "C:\Program Files\NServiceBus.Persistence.v4"
> 4. Edit the Raven.Server.exe.config: <add key="Raven/Port" value="<your port here>" />
> 5. Save the config
> 6. Start the service
> 7. Hit localhost on your new port

You should now be able to hit the RavenDB web on the new port!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to change local.config in RavenDB folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LocalConfig Port="9090" />
```

then restart raven

Answer (score 0):

To change the port of RavenDb,

#### IIS

Change the port in IIS :)

here's where mine is set (under **bindings**)

[image]

#### Development Console

1. Find the config file of the ravenDb exe or dll (depends if you're running it as an IIS website, windows server or just the console window).

`<Root RavenDb folder>\Server\RavenDb.server.exe.config`

2. Set the port, manually in the file. Change the following ...

`<add key="Raven/Port" value="*"/>`

to

`<add key="Raven/Port" value="6969"/>`

or whatever port you need/require.

#### Windows Service

No idea! i've never used it.

Good luck!